# SpringBoot - Resources - Why is there one folder for static and another one for templates?

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot for my Web application and I was wondering why I have to have two folders, one for the templates and another one for "static"(css,js,etc..). 
Can't I configure it for having just one folder, placing the "static" content inside my templates folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the folder templates contains files that are transformed server-side with a library like freemarker etc. to add dynamic content before being sent to the client, while static contains files that are sent directly as is.